# JSON String to JSON in Java

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I have a couple of txt files that gets some information from android's (call,messages,etc) database and stores it as a Cursor object.

I then convert the Cursor onto a JSON object which is then stored on a txt file on an SD card on the device. When I read from the file I get lines as a String like this one:

```
{"date":1332969098495,"duration":0,"number":"7038673588","Device_ID":"streak"}
```

I have to store the values of the String onto a MySQL table. Is there a way that I can convert this back onto a JSON or maybe a Map?

I thought about editing the String so the values are surrounded by a single quote and use the MySQL syntax to simply load the fields on the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JSONObject from the string that you have. That will pretty much give the same functionality as that of java.util.Map. For e.g,

```
String jsonStr = "json representation of your data";
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
jObj.get(yourKeyString);
//do more with your jObj here...
```

Hope this helps. Refer the [JSONObject](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.HTML) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [JSon-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html) (or) [GSon](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) libraries for this purpose.

Example GSon code would be:

```
YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(inputJson, YourObject.class);
```

**Note:**  YourObject is java class with getter/setter.

Comment: I added a buffered reader that reads from the file, used the gson.FromJson(reader, JSONOBject.class). It seems like the code is just hanging after those statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an tutorial of using GSON library to achieve typed object conversion.

http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Answer (score 0):

Sathishpaul is correct but just to clarify :

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(YourJSONString);
Long date = obj.getLong("date");
int duration = obj.getInt("duration");
```

etc..